# Fetch file names, Owner name, URL and last modified date of all files within a Master Google Drive folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying to bring in the file details from a google drive folder. It has many subfolders within and I want the details of all those files as well. I have been playing with a code and it partially worked. I can see all the file names in "Execution" but not everything gets added to my Output in Google sheet.

- Execution log (Here "Copy of" file names are the ones that are in subfolders)

[image]

- Sheet Output (Have Date modified and Owner name to the left )

[image]

Not sure what's causing this issue. Below is the code that I use.

```
function getFileNames(folder) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");

  
  var files = folder.getFiles();

  var i = 1;
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();

    sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, 4).setValues([[file.getLastUpdated(), file.getOwner().getName(), file.getName(), file.getUrl()]]);
    i++;
  }
  
  var subFolders = folder.getFolders();
  
  
  while (subFolders.hasNext()) {
    var subFolder = subFolders.next();
    
    
    getFileNames(subFolder);
  }
}


var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDER_ID');
getFileNames(folder);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, by `var i = 1;`, `sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, 4).setValues([[file.getLastUpdated(), file.getOwner().getName(), file.getName(), file.getUrl()]]);` is always run from the 1st row. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue of `I can see all the file names in "Execution" but not everything gets added to my Output in Google sheet.`.
- When `setValues` is used in a loop, the process cost will become high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this case, please run `main`.

```js
function getFileNames(folder, values = []) {
  if (folder) {
    var files = folder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      values.push([file.getLastUpdated(), file.getOwner().getName(), file.getName(), file.getUrl()])
    }
    var subFolders = folder.getFolders();
    while (subFolders.hasNext()) {
      var subFolder = subFolders.next();
      getFileNames(subFolder, values);
    }
  }
  return values;
}

function main() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDER_ID');
  var values = getFileNames(folder);
  if (values.length > 0) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  } else {
    console.log("No values are returned.")
  }
}
```